# Discord.py collect emoji reactions and make a function out of them

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a function whenever the user reacts with the check emoji or if they react with the x. So basically I have a check if the  user has a phone, if the user has a phone then you can call them. The bot sends a message in dms and reacts with a check and a x, if you click the check I want a function to happen, how can I do this?

```
    @commands.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,120,commands.BucketType.user)
async def call(self, ctx, member : discord.Member):
    phone = False
    users = await bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    client = discord.Client
    try:
        bag=users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag=[]
    for item in bag:
        name = item["item"]
        if name == "phone":
            phone = True
    if phone == False:
        await ctx.reply("You must buy a phone to call someone idiot.") 
    if phone == True:
        try:
            targetBag = users[str(target.id)]["bag"]
        except:
            targetBag=[]
        targetPhone = False
        if target:
            for item in targetBag:
                name = item["item"]
                if name =="phone":
                    targetPhone = True
            if targetPhone == False:
                await ctx.reply("Attempted user to call does not have a phone.")
            if targetPhone == True:
                channel = await target.create_dm()
                emojis=['✅', '❌']
                confirmEmoji = '✅'
                message=await channel.send(f"{ctx.author} is calling you. Do you want to answer?")
                for emoji in emojis:
                    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wait_for()` for this case. Create a response variable so that you can check and use the response to answer the phone or decline it.
You can read more about it here-
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

There are different types of events which you can pass into `wait_for()` in your case it's `reaction_add`

Hope this helped :D